# двузначные числа в str_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

```
$n = array(1, 2, 3, 33);
$v = array('один', 'два',  'три',  'тридцать три');
$mergeArr = str_replace($n, $v, '1, 2, 33');
echo $mergeArr; //выводит: один, два, тритри
```

Не могу найти подходящей функции. Или как написать самому регулярку, чтобы правильно выводило?

Comment: Зачем тут регулярка вообще? Слейте массивы в один ассоциативный, и выводите строки по числовому ключу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первыми ставьте более длинные строки для поиска

```
<?php
$n = array('33', '1', '2', '3'); 
$v = array('тридцать три', 'один', 'два', 'три'); 
$mergeArr = str_replace($n, $v, '1, 2, 33'); 
echo $mergeArr; // один, два, тридцать три
```

**UPD**

Можно использовать функцию [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php) для замены подстрок.

> strtr() может вызываться с двумя аргументами. В этом случае from должен быть массивом (array), в форме array('from' => 'to', ...). Функция возвратит строку, в которой все ключи массива будут заменены их элементами. strtr() в первую очередь заменяет более длинные ключи, причем одна и та же строка поиска используется только один раз.

```
<?php
$n = array(1, 2, 3, 33); 
$v = array('один', 'два', 'три', 'тридцать три'); 
$repl = array_combine($n, $v);
$mergeArr = strtr('1, 2, 33', $repl); 
echo $mergeArr; // один, два, тридцать три
```

Comment: можно еще и функцию сортировки по длине значения применить, вообще огонь будет

Comment: дело в том, что я сравниваю 2 массива и значения там должны идти по порядку, а шаблон постоянно меняется

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно